# What´s the position of the frequency adverb when using "there + be"?

Tags: word-order

What is the right position for the frequency verb to be put when using THERE + BE? EXAMPLES:

> There **always should** be a doorman here.
>   or
>   There **should always** be a doorman here.
>
> There **sometimes must be** order in the classroom.
>   or
>   There **must sometimes be** strict order in the classroom.

Answer (score 0):

The usual place of the adverb in the first sentence is directly before "be". You can move it if you want to; though it may sound odd, it's not impossible.

Your second example sounds a little sarcastic. You could move the adverb to the end to reinforce that meaning:
"There must be order in the class room, at least sometimes!"

Here's a link to a similar question:
[Stack Exchange English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/rule-about-order-in-modal-adverb-to-be)

"Rule about order in modal + adverb + to be"